# Some concerns about recent messages in the chatroom La Tertulia

Tags: discusión, chat

(Please jump to the ampersands at the bottom if you want the TL:DR)

English version follows

---

Compañeros:

Antes que nada, ¿puedo pedir, querido lector, que eches un ojo a [Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/), si no lo has leído todavía?

No visito [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46061/la-tertulia) con mucha frecuencia, por varias razones (e.g. falta de tiempo, hay muchas expresiones informales que francamente no entiendo, etc.), pero en estas últimas semanas he recibido consejos por varias partes, incluyendo nuestros moderadores, a utilizar Chat más y Meta menos.  En los otros sitios de SE donde participo, no he observado esa preferencia; pero "donde fueres, haz lo que vieres".

Hace varias semanas, visité La Tertulia para pedir ayuda al moderador con una etiqueta.  Así me habían dicho que debo hacer en casos de cambios pequeños que no requieren discusión.  Recibí un ping con la respuesta.

Durante esa visita corta a La Tertulia, vi que Participante A había hecho un comentario crítico a mi comentario y sobre mi estilo en general.  Charlie me defendió, y me dio una sugerencia sobre cómo hacer intervenciones menos bruscas.

Quedé con la impresión de que A no imaginaba que yo entraría y vería el comentario.  No era un insulto.  Nomás era un poco incómodo, un poco como abrir una carta escrita a otra persona, por accidente, que tiene alguna mención de mí.

Pasaron varias semanas.

Visité La Tertulia ayer para anunciar y celebrar un logro personal, que llegué a los 4,000 puntos.  Llegué con gran alegría por mi logro y por la llegada de primavera donde vivo.  Nadie me felicitó por mi logro personal, y la conversación general siguió sobre el tema de las lluvias y las sequías en diferentes partes de España.  Eso no es el motivo de este post, pero es parte del paisaje, por lo que lo menciono.

Visité otra vez hoy para pedir opiniones acerca de una etiqueta que quería hacer para "lenguaje-del-internet" o "lenguaje-técnico". Y honestamente para ver si había acaso una nota para felicitarme que quizás no había visto, porque aún tenía la esperanza de compartir mi alegría con otros.

Vi que alguien había puesto un enlace a una pregunta que hice hace tiempo en Meta acerca de la zona gris entre *nice* y *not nice*.  Como era mi pregunta, me interesó la conversación.

La transcripción de lo que vi está [aquí](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46061/2018/5/8).

Francamente no entiendo todo y no lo he leído con lupa.

Simplemente quiero pedirles:

& * & * & * & * &

Recuerden que si tú haces un comentario acerca de fulano en La Tertulia, puede llegar a pasar que fulano lo vea.  **Chat es un lugar público donde no puedes tener la expectativa de hacer comentarios privados.**  Si tu comentario pudiera dar un momento de pena, si saliera en primera plana del periódico, *no lo pongas en Chat*.  Por favor.

& * & * & * & * &

Escribo esto no con el fin de hacer recriminaciones, ni de echar culpa a nadie, ni de causar un mal momento a nadie, etc., etc.

Simplemente quiero pedir a cada participante de este sitio, que tanto estimo y aprecio:

> Pórtense bien, muchachos.  Si algo que alguien hizo te molesta, puedes
>
> - quejarte con tu mejor amigo/amiga
> - anotarlo en un lugar personal
> - levantar una bandera
> - hacer un post constructivo en Meta
> - olvidarlo porque la vida es corta
>
> Pero no lo anotes en Chat donde alguien podría leerlo por accidente y
>   sentirse mal.

---

Friends:

First, may I request, dear reader, that you take a look at [Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/), if you haven't already read it?

I don't visit [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46061/la-tertulia) very often, for various reasons (e.g. time limitations, it's common for me to see a lot of informal expressions that frankly I don't understand, etc.), but recently I've received guidance from several sources, including our moderators, to use Chat more and Meta less.  In other SE sites where I participate, I haven't seen this preference; but "When in Rome, do as the Romans do."

A few weeks ago, I visited La Tertulia to request moderator assistance with tag housekeeping, as I had been guided to do for small changes, and I was pinged in response.

During that visit to La Tertulia, I noticed that Participant A had made a critical comment about what I had written, and about my style in general.  Charlie defended me, and gave me a suggestion for how to participate with a style that would come across less brusque.

I was left with the impression that A hadn't expected me to come in and see the comment.  The comment wasn't an insult.  It was just a bit uncomfortable, rather like opening a letter written to someone else, by accident, that happens to mention me.

Several weeks went by.

Yesterday, I visited La Tertulia to announce and celebrate a personal milestone, that I reached the 4000 point mark.  I went there with pure happiness about my milestone and about the relief I felt about spring finally having arrived where I live.  No one congratulated me about my milestone, and the conversation continued on the subject of never-ending rain, and droughts, in various regions in Spain. That is not the reason I'm writing this post, but it's part of the background, hence its inclusion in this post.

I went back today to ask for opinions about making a tag for "lenguaje-del-internet" or "lenguaje-técnico".  And if I'm honest, also to see if there were a congratulatory note that I might have missed, because I was still basking in the glow and was still hoping to share the  good feeling with others.

I noticed that someone had posted a link to a question I wrote a while back on Meta about the fuzzy zone between nice and not nice.  As it was my own question, I was interested in the conversation.

The transcript of what I saw there is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46061/2018/5/8).

Frankly I don't understand everything that appears there, and I haven't read it with a fine tooth comb.

I would simply like to request:

& * & * & * & * &

Remember that if you write a comment about Joe Blow in La Tertulia, it's possible that Joe himself might see it.  **Chat is a public place where there can be no expectation of privacy.**  If your comment, published on the front page of the newspaper, might make someone squirm -- please *don't put it on Chat.*

& * & * & * & * &

I don't wish to make any recriminations, engage in finger pointing, make anyone feel bad, etc. etc.

I just want to ask everyone who participates on this site, which I respect and appreciate so much:

> *Play nice, people.  If you are bothered by something someone has done, you can*
>
> - *kvetch to your best friend*
> - *write about it in your personal journal*
> - *raise a flag*
> - *write a constructive post in Meta*
> - *let it go because life is short*
>
> But please don't write about it in Chat, where someone might read it by accident and feel bad.

Comment: Is this a general discussion about how to use the chatroom(s) or a discussion about a specific problem? If the former I don't see why we need the discussion, but feel free to elaborate more on why we need to discuss how to use the chat. If the latter, it would be best to explain the problem and how it is affecting the community.

Comment: Clarification about `moderators [instructed me] to use Chat more and Meta less`. I believe that the point was to use the different tools and resources of the stack in a more effective way. The Mods have not encouraged (nor discouraged) the use of one (meta or chat) over the other to anyone. Mods promote making a more effective use of the tools to engage the community successfully on meta and use chat for other quick questions, requests, general talk or even 1-on-1 with mods or other users .

Comment: Siendo consecuente con lo comentado por @Diego en su respuesta, viniste al chat a comentar tu logro y, como dices, nadie respondió, por lo que incumplimos el "be nice" por omisión de la felicitación, así que por mi parte te pido disculpas y te felicito por tu logro, que espero no sea el último. Por otra parte, apoyo la respuesta de walen. ¿Cómo debemos usar el chat? Como queramos, siempre que seamos amables. Y si crees que la conversación no discurre al nivel deseado, propón un tema interesante para hablar. En vez de oponerte a la corriente, modifícala a tu antojo. Be water, my friend.

Comment: Creo que los que usamos el chat somos conscientes de que es público y que cualquiera puede leer lo que hay en él. Yo al menos no digo nada que no quiero que se sepa, si hablo de alguien en el chat suele ser por cosas que han ocurrido en el sitio y no tengo problema en discutir el tema con quien corresponda, si algo que he dicho le molesta o cree que no es correcto puede hablarlo conmigo o levantar un *flag* si lo cree conveniente.

Comment: No creo que no felicitarte por el logro sea algo que deba sentarte mal, en ese momento solo estaba yo en el chat, leí lo que pusiste y seguí la conversación con el tema de la primavera, no dije nada sobre tu logro de editar etiquetas, simplemente porque tampoco pensé que tenía que decir nada, de hecho no lo recordaba hasta que he visto la captura. La gente entra en el chat mientras hace otras cosas, las conversaciones no siempre son fluidas ni se hace caso a todo lo que se dice, también me ha pasado decir algo y que nadie lo comente pero la verdad es no le doy ninguna importancía a esas cosas.

Comment: Nota de moderador: he convertido la respuesta en una edición a la pregunta. También convertí la respuesta en comentario de forma temporal, para que no se perdieran los interesantes comentarios que había generado (si bien observo que los +1 que tenían se han perdido :/). Espero haber contribuido a hacer esto más entendible. Si no es así, no dudéis en utilizar un _flag_ para tirarme de las orejas y que lo corrija.

Comment: En La Tertulia y hay veces que la conversación fluye y otras que no. Al fin y al cabo, es como sentarse en un banco de la plaza del pueblo e ir charlando con quien pase. Con el matiz, claro está, que la gente está simultáneamente en otras cosas, por lo que la atención es limitada. Sería bueno, aparente, tomar el chat como tal. He leído y releído la conversación y no veo nada _punible_. Y en cualquier caso, traer esto a Meta con una visión apocalíptica tampoco ayuda: habla de cosas concretas, líneas fuera de tono, en lugar de hacer una censura genérica que no pueda rebatirse ni debatirse.

Comment: @Charlie - Thanks for the congrats -- feels good! // I did not mention the lack of interest in celebrating my small (but meaningful for me) accomplishment as a complaint; it was part of the background.  Nevertheless, your kind comment is definitely appreciated.

Comment: @fedorqui - I don't mind your having separated out the interpreted part.  For most paragraphs, I drafted the Spanish first, and then played the role of interpreter for the sake of the participant who requested Spanish, and anyone else who might find it helpful.  I put on my old interpreter hat. I was surprised that that approach caused so much trouble, and I apologize for that. I'm sorry you had to put in so much time reformatting. // Countless Spanish speakers in the US (and elsewhere?) muddle through phone calls and in-person visits to the bank, the doctor, the insurance company, etc., with

Comment: the help of legions of paid and volunteer interpreters, and somehow life goes on.  When I communicate with the doctor and the nursing home in Germany, I get my spouse to play interpreter.  Maybe it's not ideal, but it works.

Comment: @fedorqui - I don't believe in punishment.  I believe in supporting people to behave well, helping people understand what is desirable, what is not desirable, and why the undesirable isn't good for someone or for a group of people. // As I said, I do not wish to point a finger at anyone, and I do not wish to provide specific quotes here about the chat comments which, in my opinion, could be hurtful, and which StackExchange leadership has instructed us recently to be especially vigilant about -- specifically in the Chat environment.  For people's convenience, I have provided the relevant ...

Comment: ... transcript.  I just don't think it's a good idea to say, in Chat or on a park bench in the public square, "So-and-so (Fulano) did this, or that, and this is what I think about it."  If you would like me to zoom in on a particular portion of the transcript and micro-analyze it with you, I'd rather do that in private.  As for the previous comment in Chat about me, although I don't have a transcript to share, I think I provided an accurate description, including the helpful action of a positive bystander, whom I identified by name.  I am feeling *grilled* about what I tried to present as...

Comment: ... *constructive* feedback.  Now, what progress exactly is made here at this site when lots of people, including the moderators, publicly turn and start pointing their arrows at one individual, the person who constructively called participants' attention to a perceived problem?  If, in fact, there is no problem, then all this vociferous denial isn't really needed, I would think. You, and others, are free to think, "Oh geesh, aparente's turned a molehill into a mountain," and then turn to something more worthy of your/their attention.  Please, stop attacking the messenger and focus on...

Comment: ... the message.  If the message seems unproductive to you, or anyone reading this, you/they are welcome to ignore it and just go about your normal business, here and elsewhere. Anywhere else in StackExchange, a user is *encouraged* to post on Meta about a concern, and to raise a custom flag if s/he feels a custom message would help explain the reason for the flag. Here, however, rather than focusing on the message I'm communicating, there are constant complaints about the *way* I'm presenting the message.  Could you please set aside your annoyance with the form and format?

Comment: We are trying to focus on the problems, so we can work on them. You have raised your concerns about something you read in the chat, so I assume we should discuss about that thing. If you had asked about how to behave in chat without any reference to what you read, we would have discussed about guidelines in a general way. But I think it is quite unfair to come in Meta to explain how shocked you are about how people just did something, to then get angry because we want to check what exactly was that happened.

Comment: @fedorqui - I will be happy to point out the specifics that concerned me, in a more private way.  I don't want to call anyone out in public.  I tried to make that clear already, and I apologize if I didn't get that message across effectively. // I'm not angry because you want to check what happened. // It's part of the SE model to bring issues such as this to Meta. At the same time, although I don't think I should be blamed or criticized for not having posed a general question about guidelines, as you suggest, I do love the idea -- I think you should go for it!

Comment: You said that there was a problem, and my opinion is that there is a mechanism already in place for those situations, which is _flagging_. Instead of continuing claiming that there is a problem that only you see or care, understand that the policy in meta is "lets not discuss something so specific (a particualr comment) but something more generic (being rude - anywhere in the stack). In such situations just flag and/or remind of the 'Be nice' policy. No need to create a meta post to discuss every single infraction". No need to point out specifics. Just flag. (Or discuss a more general problem)

Comment: @Diego - I described an observation from a couple of weeks ago, and I provided a transcript of a similar, recent observation.  I was concerned. I have proposed that people apply the "newspaper headline" test, which a professor explained to me in grad school: If it would be embarrassing for a Chat comment I'm considering writing to be published in the newspaper with a headline "Aparente says 'quote' in Chat," then it would probably be best to find some more private way of self-expression.  Another approach: *If you can't find something positive to say about the person, don't say anything.*

Comment: I disagree with that newspaper approach Why wouldn’t someone be allowed to quote your exact words? If the quote is embarrassing, is there a problem with the quote or with the original comment? Now, if they pretend you said something that you didn’t, mock you for your opinion or for being "wrong" about something then that is a different story. Quoting is not necessarily mocking/being rude. In any case, I’m repeating myself: **flag rude/abusive content and stop micromanaging the way other users should contribute in the stack**. Nothing else to add, so this is my last contribution in this thread

Comment: @Diego - No need for repetition (on either of our parts). // You asked a question about the newspaper test, and I am happy to answer.  It looks as though I wasn't clear and you didn't understand what I was trying to convey.  Let me make a fresh start.  I went to a professor during grad school to ask advice about an ethical situation.  His advice: "Make sure that whatever you do, it will pass the newspaper test.  The newspaper test consists of the following: Imagine that your action is published, with an accurate description, on the front page of the newspaper in big type: 'Aparente ...

Comment: ... Does Such-and-So.' If that prospect makes you squirm, i.e. if that headline and article would make people question your ethics in having chosen that action... then that would be a poor choice."  What I'm asking fellow participants here to do is to pause before hitting "Send" on a Chat comment written about another participant.  To pause and think, How would my comment look to others?  How would the person I was speaking about feel, if s/he saw what I wrote?  How would I feel, if someone else wrote that about me (assuming that I would be unlikely to see it), and I came across it? ...

Comment: ... What I'm asking people to do, in short, is to be more *circumspect* in their comments about specific individuals who participate here.  "Be kind to your fine feathered friends, 'cause that duck could be somebody's mother; be kind to your friends in the swamp, because it's dark and dreary there...."

Comment: @aparente001 we all agree that we have to be careful with what people say in chat, which is described on Dieg's answer with the _Be nice_ policy. That being said, you have brought this debate in here for specific lines, which are the things to have discussed. Following my parallelism from my first comment, it is not normal to go to the center of the village and say _hey, you are behaving rudely_ without any previous interaction and without giving a reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

As we please, as long as we keep it civilized, IMHO.

On-topic conversation gets precedence, not because of any rule but because we like Spanish (else we wouldn't be here), however off-topic conversation is also allowed, of course.

If you have any problems with [blonfu and me talking about another user's interaction with SO.es mods](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/conversation/middle-school-gossip-o-o), feel free to flag the chat messages. 
I think it was a rather irrelevant conversation, but it seems like you felt "offended by proxy" by it.

If I found some inappropriate remarks in chat I'd just comment in chat "*Hey guys, I don't think you two should be talking about someone else's behavior*" because I don't like to unnecessarily escalate things, but that's just me.

If you want to go the Meta way instead, there's a recent Meta post about chat policing: [We're more aggressively enforcing self-moderation in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309645/were-more-aggressively-enforcing-self-moderation-in-chat). You might want to post your concerns there, too, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que se puede responder con solo dos palabras:

### [Be nice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Para empezar, lamento mucho que ciertos comentarios (críticos con tus "comentarios y estilo en general") o la falta de ellos (felicitándote por alcanzar los 4000 puntos de reputación) te hayan disgustado. Dicho esto, también he de decir que no siempre tenemos (ninguno de nosotros) el lujo de recibir *feedback* o comentarios *edulcorados*, de recibir solo elogios pero ninguna crítica, o de recibirlos solo en la manera o método de nuestra preferencia.

Cuando un comentario parece "pasarse de la raya" lo suyo es **levantar un flag**. Como se explica en la sección [Nuestro Modelo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/flagging):

> If the inappropriate content occurs in comment, hover over the offending comment and click the small flag icon that appears.

Se puede levantar un flag también en los comentarios de los chats, no solo en los comentarios de los posts (o sobre los propios posts). Los moderadores actuaremos sobre los flags y examinaremos ese contenido potencialmente "*rude or abusive*".

Entiendo, por el problema explicado en tu respuesta a tu propia pregunta, que esta pregunta no es una discusión real sobre el uso del chat, sino una discusión sobre un problema particular o un recordatorio del "be nice".

Por tanto, habría sido suficiente con **levantar un flag** sobre los comentarios ofensivos (desgraciadamente, no se puede hacer nada acerca de la ausencia de comentarios felicitándote por tu logro de los 4000 puntos de reputación. Podrías levantar un flag al respecto, pero sería un mal uso del flag porque no se puede tachar a la comunidad de *grosera* por no hacer esos comentarios ni se puede obligar a la comunidad a hacerlos).

Levantar un flag y/o dejar un comentario acerca de la política de [Be Nice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) es la manera de actuar frente al contenido que consideramos pernicioso para el sitio, la comunidad o un usuario en particular.

**No podemos ni debemos crear un post meta para discutir un situación particular que simplemente requiere levantar un flag**. Los post de meta son para discutir problemas más generales sobre la marcha del stack. Sí podemos discutir por ejemplo una pregunta particular que está en la línea entre off-topic y on-topic (o que tiene un problema parecido), y aprender más sobre los límites del sitio y mejorarlos, pero un post meta que en realidad solo es **la divulgación pública de un flag** no aporta demasiado al stack.

En mi opinión, no hay mucho que discutir aquí. La apreciación sobre esos comentarios puede ser muy subjetiva y no se señala un problema (un problema general sobre el que podamos actuar y mejorar el stack). Creo que esta pregunta y su autorrespuesta no son más que un recordatorio de la política del

### [Be nice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice),

por lo que no creo que vayamos a sacar nada positivo más allá de lo que ya sabemos. Tampoco creo que la petición de no hacer ciertos comentarios en ese canal público merezca un post de meta. Esa petición entra en conflicto con la libertad de los usuarios para hacer uso del chat. Así que entiendo que los usuarios de chat seguirán usando su buen juicio sobre su libertad para expresarse en chat y si en algún momento esa libertad entra en conflicto con las normas de convivencia **poned un flag** para que los moderadores actuemos sobre ese contenido.

Comment: Please see responses elsewhere on the page.